# How do I improve differentiation of long paths when searching for a file when there are others of the same name in VS Code's Quick Open feature?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code, when holding down <kbd>cmd+p</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> Windows) I get a menu which lets me quickly access files in my project.

The issue is, when I have multiple files with the same name, that have recently been accessed, VS Code shows the entire path but does not show the remaining directory name, making me guess which file is the one I want.

For example:
[image]

Is there a way to clear the file path up or shorten, via settings, so that I can discern which file is the one I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible right now, but there's a related Pull Request that you might be interested in subscribing to: [modify the feature of quick input, when overflowed the elipsses shows… #145450](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/145450).

If you're interested in history, there are two past issue tickets that have been raised about this: [Better represent long file names in quick open #58040](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58040) (closed for not receiving enough community support), [File path in deeply nested folders is truncated from the wrong side in quick open #156062](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156062) (closed as a duplicate of #58040).